# How to correctly manipulate tar files in memory with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tar, tarfile

I need to update a tar archive totally in memory. The reason is that I have an encrypted bundle with the tar file (which contains sensitive data), that I cannot save the unencrypted form (the tar archive) to disk.
Right now, I'm able to read it perfectly, but saving the new file ends in an unexpected result.

There will be no more discussion about encryption on this topic. It was just a brief description of my need for doing things the way I'm doing.

My goal is to open a tar file, remove some files from it, add some others and save the new `.tar` file.
I will need to do it using `BytesIO` objects. But I'm not even able to create a new tar file from a previous one in a much simpler scenario.

Simple scenario reading and saving (copying) tar files on disk:

```sh
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3595 Jun  3 23:10 archive.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   50 Jun  3 23:19 gibberish
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1024 Jun  3 13:07 some_file.log

$ tar cfz example.tar.gz *
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3595 Jun  3 23:10 archive.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3059 Jun  4 09:08 example.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   50 Jun  3 23:19 gibberish
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1024 Jun  3 13:07 some_file.log
$ tar tfz example.tar.gz
archive.pem
gibberish
some_file.log
```

Using a simple Python code to read `example.tar.gz` and save a new `example.tar` (just a copy):

```py
import tarfile
with tarfile.open('example.tar.gz', 'r') as tr, tarfile.open('example.tar', 'w') as tw: 
    for m in tr.getmembers(): 
        print(f"{m.name} size = {m.size}") 
        tw.addfile(m)
```

The output from running this code is:

```
archive.pem size = 3595
gibberish size = 50
some_file.log size = 1024
```

And the new directory looks like this:

```sh
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  3595 Jun  3 23:10 archive.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 10240 Jun  4 09:16 example.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  3059 Jun  4 09:08 example.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    50 Jun  3 23:19 gibberish
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  1024 Jun  3 13:07 some_file.log
$ tar tf example.tar       
some_file.log
```

Only one file is listed and the new tar file always has 10k size.
Most of the file is filled with '\0' bytes.

If the above code worked correctly, what I really want to do as a simplified example would be something close to:

Updating an archive, by removing one file and adding another:

```py
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO


def _update_tar(tarfileobj, file_to_add, file_to_remove):
    outio = BytesIO()

    with tarfile.open(fileobj=tarfileobj) as _in, tarfile.TarFile(
        fileobj=outio, mode="w"
    ) as _out:
        for member in _in.getmembers():
            print(f"Read {member.name} from archive.")
            if member.name != file_to_remove:
                print(f"Add {member.name} to the new archive!")
                _out.addfile(member)
        _out.add(file_to_add)
    outio.seek(0)
    return outio


tarbytes = open(
    "example.tar.gz", "rb"
).read()  # Those bytes will come from a decrypt function
input_io = BytesIO(tarbytes)

output_io = _update_tar(input_io, "new_file.txt", "gibberish")

with open("example.tar", "wb") as file: # Those bytes will go to an encrypt func
    file.write(output_io.read())
```

```sh
$ echo "Just a simple new file" >  new_file.txt
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  3595 Jun  3 23:10 archive.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  3059 Jun  4 09:08 example.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    50 Jun  3 23:19 gibberish
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    23 Jun  4 09:45 new_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  1024 Jun  3 13:07 some_file.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   813 Jun  4 09:46 updatetar.py
$ python updatetar.py
Read archive.pem from archive.
Add archive.pem to the new archive!
Read gibberish from archive.
Read some_file.log from archive.
Add some_file.log to the new archive!
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  3595 Jun  3 23:10 archive.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 10240 Jun  4 09:46 example.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  3059 Jun  4 09:08 example.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    50 Jun  3 23:19 gibberish
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    23 Jun  4 09:45 new_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  1024 Jun  3 13:07 some_file.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   813 Jun  4 09:46 updatetar.py
```

The result is the same. This 10K file being generated.

I'm using `Python 3.8.3` on a Linux machine.

Anyone could help me with the right way to update a tar file in memory in Python?

Comment: In your simplified example, `tw.addfile(m, fileobj=tr.extractfile(m))` should add the file with its contents.